# How to see RecyclerView and other support lib sources in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio, android-support-library

I'm using Android Studio **3.0** and my project uses RecyclerView

```
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
```

When I try to open RecyclerView class sources (with go to class dialog), I see only decompiled version of the class. Same thing happens to all other classes from support lib.

Some of my colleagues use Android Studio **3.0** and have the same problem. But others have Studio **2.3** and everything is working OK for them.

Is there any workaround to see RecyclerView and other support lib sources in Studio **3.0**?